# iOS testing methodology

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios

When I write any new code I generally add two custom macros like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  
{
    NOT_IMPLEMENTED();
    NOT_TESTED();
}
```

Where these macros are just something simple like:

`#define NOT_IMPLEMENTED() do{ __asm int 3 } while(0)`

I use this for two reasons: 1) I can grep my source for functions I haven't implemented or stepped through in the debugger and 2) If I hit one of these conditions it just halts the debugger at that point rather than throwing an exception like NSAssert does.  This way I can look at the callstack and proceed with execution from the point of where the int 3 was hit (P.S. 'int 3' only works on intel processors).

Now here's the rub.  For things like 'didFailWithError' there's almost no documentation on this message can be sent.  Ideally, I'd like to build a dummy webservice that knows how to trigger this condition so I know that I'm handling this type of condition.  This is just an example.  If you've ever worked with the in-app purchase API there's equally nebulous error delegates that give no indication of when they might be called.

I guess what I'm asking is what do other developers do to test error delegates that are available in many of the iOS libraries?  Especially for the ones that give no indication on how they can be triggered.